# How do I add an embed to my website like this

Tags: embed

This is an example when someone posts a link on discord it appears with this box and has some text on it. How do I add this to my website? [Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNQDV.png)
[image]

Comment: kindly have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use open graph meta tag properties. See Facebook's developer guidelines for examples.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup